# C++: Issue with some Input and Output and Sum

Tags: c++

So, it's me again.
I've solved a lot of problems with sums and numbers in the past weeks and I've got to a point where I can easily solve them.
However I found a problem which I cannot solve so I came here to ask you guys if any of you have any spare time to help me.
I'd be very thankful for that.
So, the problem is that I have a number n, and a number m, there are 2 sums, the sum of all the numbers lower or equal to n, and the other sum of all the numbers lower or equal to m.
There is a variable S which is the difference between those sums, but the S is got from a .in file.
The problem is that I have to type a value for S in the .in file and to write a code that gets me the all the value for n and all the value for m in a .out file.
For example if I put 10 in the .in file I have to get n: 10, m: 9, n: 4, m: 0 in the .out file.

I've made something like this but it's wrong because I only get the sums of n, and m but I have no n , and m..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

ifstream inFile;

inFile.open("s2.in");

int S;

inFile >> S;

int n;
int m;

int Sgn = 0;

int Sgm = 0;

int c = 1;
int r = 1;

//Sum n
for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
    Sgn += c;
    c += r;
}

//Sum m
for ( int i = 1; i <= m; i++ ){
    Sgm += c;
    c += r;
}

S = Sgn - Sgm;

ofstream out("s2.out");
out << "\n n: " << n << "\n m: " << m << endl;

}
```

And 1 ≤ S ≤ 2.000.000.000;
And n has to be > m;

So I can do something like this:

```
if ( n > m ){
   //Sum n
for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
    Sgn += c;
    c += r;
}

//Sum m
for ( int i = 1; i <= m; i++ ){
    Sgm += c;
    c += r;
}

S = Sgn - Sgm;
}
```

Like, if n: 10 and m: 9. It'll be ( 1+2+...+10 ) - ( 1+2+...+9 )= 10
And if n: 4 and m: 0. It'll be ( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ) - 0 = 10

Comment: You'll have to say more about what the values of `n` and `m` are supposed to be. Your "For example..." seems to be just arbitrary values.

Comment: This problem is more about mathematics than programming. You will need to write down and analyse formulas for such sums, solve equations symbolically, and only then proceed to code it up.

Comment: @n.m. I already solved the sums but I don't know n, and m like Pete Bekcer said have no values, You only get one value, the value of S, and based off of that you have to calculate somehow n and m I tried but I don't get anywhere, again I know how to calculate the sums of n and m like in the code I showed you but the difference of those has to be equal to S and if S is 10 the difference is 10 but how do I find n and m..

Comment: @PeteBecker there's really not anything else more about them, only n has to be bigger than m, and 1 ≤ S ≤ 2.000.000.000, the value of S goes into .in file and based off of that the program I code has to get the values for n and m, with the condition that the sum of n - the sum of m is equal to S.

Comment: If that's all you know about `n` and `m`, the problem is underspecified. In other words, it's impossible to solve. This isn't a programming problem.

Comment: You need to *solve an equation* for n and m, and you need to come up with that equation first. No amount of coding skills will help you with these tasks.

Comment: @PeteBecker It is a programming problem, I literally thought the same but I really have to solve it and I tried many things mathematically but I just can't find anything more, all I get is S and I have to find n and m.., the sums for n and m are called Gauss Sums by the way, those are easily made with a for loop but like the backtracking to get n and m is a little harder..

Comment: @PeteBecker right, this is a maths problem, but why do you think it's impossible to solve? There's always a finite amount of solutions.

Comment: @n.m. Can you help me with the equation then? The sum for n is equal to n * ( n + 1)/2 and the sum for m is the same (m * ( m+1))/2, so n(n+1)/2 - m(m+1)/2 = 10
n(n+1) - m(m+1) = 20, so what after that

Comment: @n.m. All of those equations with the condition that S is equal to 10.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's correct but I found something guys, whatever the S is, a first pair of n and m is S and S - 1.

Comment: Just like in the example , if S = 10, a first pair is 10 and 9

Comment: I did it with 2, if S = 2, the pair is 2 and 1, if S = 3, a pair is 3  and 2 and 2 and 0

Comment: If S = 1 , the pair is 1 and 0

Comment: Good, you now play with this formula and simplify it as much as possible.

Comment: The only thing is that I have to find all the possible pairs not only one.., like for S = 10, there are 10 9 and 4 0, for S = 3 there are 3 2 and 2 0 , for S = 5 there are 5 and 4 and 3 and 1

Comment: You want to try to represent that n(n+1) - m(m+1) as a product of two numbers perhaps.

Comment: The S and S-1 pair is correct but I have to find all the possible pairs for the S input, then the code has to calculate every other n and m and their sums' difference is equal to S..

Comment: I got an idea though, maybe I can test every number below S and S - 1 so n2 would be S - 1 and m2 would be S - 3 and I can make some for loop and so and calculate those numbers' sums and if the sums' difference is S out << numbers..

Comment: oh it's wrong because it tests like 4 and 3 and so but it doesn't test 4 and 0 and 5 and 1 ..

Comment: Try using `(m+k)(m+k-1)/2-m(m-1)/2=km+k(k-1)/2=S` then you can just brute force on `k` and find corresponding `m`'s and `n=m+k`. For example for `k=1` you get `m=S`

Comment: Yes a first pair is indeed n = S and m = S - 1, but can you help me with the code for that, I am not that advanced, and is that Arithmetic Progression?